# Tengo un inconveniente al hace un logout con php y google

Tags: php, local-storage, apigoogle

Tengo un sistema en el que inicio sesión con **Google**, al hacer el login todo bien pero cuando cierro la sesión en el sistema, **me cierra la sesión de google** y no se como solucionar este problema, mi código de logout escrito en **php** es:

```html
<?php
session_start();
// although 2nd and 3rd line is not needed session_destroy() is needed,
// but just to be extra sure that no session remains in the cache.
$_SESSION = array();
unset($_SESSION);
session_destroy();
header("location:index.php");
?>
```

este código lo ejecuto con el botón:

```html
<a class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-google-plus" href="<?php echo LOGOUT_URL; ?>">
  <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i> Logout
</a>
```

Que defino en mi config.php

```html
/* logout both from google and your site **/
define("LOGOUT_URL", "https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout?continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/logout?continue=". urlencode(SITE_URL."google/logout.php"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que es mas bien un problema de logica, si no quieres que pase eso, simplemente destruye la session en tu sistema (logout), y no de google. Al momento de que se haga un login en tu sistema, se haria automatico si ya tiene iniciada sesion en google, o bien se requerira el inicio de sesion. Asi comunmente se hacen todos los login con apps de terceros como facebook, twitter,linkedin, etc.